# How do I replace both matching patterns in a line using sed?

Tags: sed

#### TL;DR

Given this:

```
$ echo "-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl -lnghttp2.14 -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3.0" | \
    sed "s: -lnghttp2[^[:space:]]* : lib/libnghttp2.a :g"
-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl lib/libnghttp2.a -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3.0
```

Why aren't both `-lnghttp2.14` and `-lnghttp2` being replaced with `lib/libnghttp2.a`? Shouldn't the `:g` argument make sed replace both?

#### Longer Version

I need to replace the `-l<library>` lines in a command with the corresponding `.a` paths. I know the paths already, so I think this should be doable via a simple series of sed commands. But I'm facing an issue that I can minimally reproduce like so:

```
$ echo "-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl -lnghttp2.14 -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3.0" | \
    sed "s: -lnghttp2[^[:space:]]* : lib/libnghttp2.a :g"
-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl lib/libnghttp2.a -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3.0
```

This output is not what I expect. I want both `-lnghttp2.14` and `-lnghttp2` to be replaced with `lib/libnghttp2.a`. Thus, I want this output:

```
-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl lib/libnghttp2.a lib/libnghttp2.a -lnghttp3.0
```

Instead only `-lnghttp2.14` is replaced. I notice that if I switch the order of `-lnghttp2.14` and `-lnghttp2`, then, again, only the first occurrence of the two nghttp2 libraries is replaced. I thought that the `g` argument to sed would replace multiple matching patterns, but it doesn't seem to be doing this for me. Can someone help me come up with the proper invocation of sed to replace both of these with the desired `.a` path?

I've reproduced this on both MacOS and Centos 8.

Comment: Hint: why doesn't `echo aaaaa | sed s:aaaa:bbbb:g` print `bbbbb`?

Answer (score 1):

My problem is that my search pattern has spaces on both sides of the `-l<library>`. With that restriction, only the first of the two match because the second doesn't have the preceding space. If I remove the preceding space, then both of the words are matched and replaced. Thus:

```
$ echo "-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl -lnghttp2.14 -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3.0" | \
    sed "s:-lnghttp2[^[:space:]]* :lib/libnghttp2.a :g"
-lngtcp2_crypto_openssl lib/libnghttp2.a lib/libnghttp2.a -lnghttp3.0
```